# Returning HTTP code to POST form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, http

I have a very simple view which contains a form. This form contains 2 select fields populated with data from the database.

Let's say the first select contains "Banana", "Apple", "Orange". The second one contains "Burger", "Pizza", "Hot Dog".

I'm submitting the form (POST) and saving the combination in a table of my database. Before actually saving, I'm checking if the combination doesn't already exist. I don't want to save "Banana - Burger" twice.

If the combination already exists I'm returning the following:

```
session(['error' => 'This combination already exists.']);
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

This brings me back to my form, and shows the error message in a popup.

How can I return the proper HTTP code (409 in this instance)?

Comment: i think for that you need ajax form submit

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in your laravel validation for that. Replace your table name and field name in below example.

```
$data = $request->all();
$request->validate([
'fruits' => [
    'required',
    Rule::exists('fruits')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('fruit_name', $data['fruit_name']);
    }),
],
'foods' => [
    'required',
    Rule::exists('foods')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('food_name', $data['food_name']);
    })
]
]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You also would need to use the [old](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-old) method in order to show the old values on the form.